# How to set infinite shared access signature policy in azure?

Tags: c#, windows, azure, azure-storage

I am trying to set a shared access policy so that the user has infinite SharedAccessExpiryTime. I will track their access policies so that they can be revoked if needed.

From [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10135133/how-do-you-setup-shared-access-signature-with-more-than-1-year-expiration-at-azu), the answer states there is a mechanism for setting an infinite expiration time. I did some searching and was not able to find this, how can this be done?

Currently, I simulate infinite by providing some large values for expiration time:

```
         SharedAccessTablePolicy policy = new SharedAccessTablePolicy()
        {
            SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(500),

            Permissions = SharedAccessTablePermissions.Add
            | SharedAccessTablePermissions.Delete
            | SharedAccessTablePermissions.Update
            | SharedAccessTablePermissions.Query
        };
```

Comment: In the Spring 2012 release that went out a few weeks ago, there were updates announced to Shared Access Signatures. For blobs, the 1-hour SAS limit has been lifted. The MSDN article is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2012/06/12/introducing-table-sas-shared-access-signature-queue-sas-and-update-to-blob-sas.aspx), which includes quite a bit of sample code spanning SAS for queues, tables, and blobs.